# Fastest Method to Format

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I have a Python 2.7 script that transforms various data and outputs it to an XLSX via OpenPyXL 2.4.5.  Currently I'm iterating through all the cells, which I've narrowed down using "max_row" and "max_column".  This doesn't appear very fast or efficient to me.  What's the fastest way to set the following?   If you could suggest general methodologies, I would appreciate it.  The rough benchmarks below are for Windows 7 SP1 x64 with 16 GB RAM and an Intel i7-3740QM@2.69 GHz.

- Borders (Formatting 35880 cells takes 40s.)
- Fonts and Alignment (Formatting 35880 cells takes 42s.)
- Shading (Formatting 35880 cells takes 28s.)
- Hiding Unused Row/Column (Hiding 16,380 columns x 1,039,606 rows takes many minutes.  Hiding only the columns takes .2s.)

Below is the iteration methodology.

```
def format_xlsx(csv_list, ws_to_format):
    """ Use OpenPyXL to format a XLSX. """
    process_start = timer()
    for row in csv_list:
        count = count + 1
        ws_to_format.append(row)
    row_count = ws_to_format.max_row
    column_count = ws_to_format.max_column
    for y_axis in range(1, column_count+1):
        for x_axis in range(1, row_count+1):
            ws_to_format = xlsx_borders(ws_to_format, x_axis, y_axis)
            ws_to_format = xlsx_shading(ws_to_format, x_axis, y_axis)
            ws_to_format = xlsx_font_and_alignment(ws_to_format, x_axis, y_axis)
    ws_to_format = xlsx_hide_unused_colrow(ws_to_format)
    return
```

Below is the methodology to hide unused rows/columns.

```
def xlsx_hide_unused_colrow(ws_to_format):
    row_count = ws_to_format.max_row
    column_count = ws_to_format.max_column
    start_range = column_number_to_letter(column_count+2)
    end_range = column_number_to_letter(16384)
    ws_to_format.column_dimensions.group(start_range, end_range, hidden=True)
    start_range = row_count+2
    for y in xrange(start_range, 1048577):
        ws_to_format.row_dimensions[y].hidden=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `ws.max_row` or `ws.max_column` within loops as they are calculated every time they're called. As the size of the worksheet is not changing during your work, then they only need to be called once.

Furthermore, applying styles to row and column dimensions probably won't do what you expect it to do, please refer to the documentation about this. You need to apply the styles to the cells in the relevant rows and columns. And use named styles if you have a lot of cells to format.

Comment: -Thanks for the pointer.   I'm a novice at Python, so excuse the question if it's silly, but haven't I specified "max_row"/"max_column" outside the for loop?

Comment: You call `max_column` in your nested function and you call this function in a for loop.